# Question of lifycycle callbacks of beans in Spring

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

Spring documentation describes that beans managed by Ioc container are implicitly pre-instantiated by default other than specifying them as being lazy-initialized. I define a child bean definition A which inherits the configuration data from its parent bean definition B. Both of them have an  attribute specified on the  element. Then I retrieved an instance of bean A through the Ioc container and I found the Ioc container just called the bean A initialization method. Why the Ioc container didn't call the initialization method of bean B which was instantiated at startup?

```
<bean id="student" class="com.ford.spring.pojo.Student" lazy-init="true" init-method="init">
        <property name="age" value="20"/>
        <property name="gender" value="male"/>
        <property name="name" value="porro"/>
        <property name="id" value="1"/>
</bean>
<bean id="player"
          class="com.ford.spring.pojo.Player"
          parent="student" init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
        <property name="nationality" value="Italy"/>
</bean>
```

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config-metadata.xml");
Player player = (Player) applicationContext.getBean("player");
applicationContext.close();
System.out.println(player);
```

Why the Ioc container didn't call the initialization method of bean B which was instantiated at startup?

Comment: The beans in your config are called player and student, not A and B.

Comment: The parent attribute means that the child configuration inherits the configuration data from the parent configuration. It doesn't mean that a parent bean is actually created.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/child-bean-definitions.html#page-title) :

> A child bean definition inherits scope, constructor argument values,
> property values, and method overrides from the parent, with the option
> to add new values. **Any scope, initialization method, destroy method,
> or static factory method settings that you specify override the
> corresponding parent settings.**

So first of all , it only make sense to configure the `init-method` of the child bean if its `init-method` is different from the parent bean.  If both child and parent beans has the same `init-method` , it is not necessary to configure the `init-method` on the child bean.

Second, whether the initialisation method will execute its parent initialisation method or not is its implementation details which from the bean definition point of view , it does not care about it. It only care you tell it what is the initialisation method such that it will simply execute it after it creates a bean instance and that 's it.

So if you want `Player` 's initialisation method to execute its parent 's init. method , you can implement it as :

```java
public class Player extends Student{

   
  void init(){
     super.init();
     //do other player initialisation codes here..
  }

}
```

Otherwise , you can implement it as :

```java
public class Player extends Student{

   
  void init(){
     //do player initialisation codes here..
  }

}
```